# Access NoSQL database like CouchDB with AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, couchdb

What open-source library can I use to access `CouchDB` rest API?

I will be accessing from `AppEngine` so I the closest library that could work is that of that access `CouchDB` using its Rest interface, there may be a little work to port the low-level access of the library to use `URLFetch` or something that works with AppEngine

Comment: If you're asking if someone has layered something on `urlfetch` to abstract accessing CouchDB, I haven't heard of such a thing.

Comment: Not really, I may need to port it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine [implements java.net interface using the URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet), so any [CouchDB java libraries](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Related_Projects#Libraries) relying on `java.net` for network communication should work.